# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable while refrencing 2d array in python

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to find the lowest score in a list of contestant numbers and scores. On line 6 I get the error:

```
if score[u[1]] == score[0]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I am trying to check through the whole 2d array with the loop to find which score matches with the lowest score awarded and retrieve the contestant number

```
for x in range(contestants):
    CN = x+1
    score1.insert(x,[[CN],[score[x]]])
    score.sort
    for u in score:
        if score[u[1]] == score[0]:
            KO = score[u[0]]
            print (KO)
```

Scores looks like this:

```
 for i in range (contestants):
    j1 = int(input("Judge 1 enter your score for the contestant: "))
    j2 = int(input("Judge 2 enter your score for the contestant: "))
    j3 = int(input("Judge 3 enter your score for the contestant: "))
    j4 = int(input("Judge 4 enter your score for the contestant: "))
    j5 = int(input("Judge 5 enter your score for the contestant: "))
    print("Round over, next contstant")
    scores = [j1,j2,j3,j4,j5]

    scoreJ1.append(scores[0])
    scoreJ2.append(scores[1])
    scoreJ3.append(scores[2])
    scoreJ4.append(scores[3])
    scoreJ5.append(scores[4])


    scores.sort()
    scores.pop(0)
    scores.pop(3)
    #proud of this
    score.insert(i,scores[1]+scores[2]+scores[0])
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should show us what `score` looks like.

Comment: Please add code to your question, not in comment, it will be way more readable

Comment: sorr about that, should be ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting is `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. Let's break this down:

- `TypeError` is telling you that you are trying to apply an inappropriate operation somewhere
- `is not subscriptable` is telling you that the inappropriate operation is putting a pair of `[ ]` after something.
- `'int' object is not subscriptable` is telling you that you are trying to do it to an int.

Now let's consider the line of code which generated this error:

```
if score[u[1]] == score[0]:
```

Notice that there are three pairs of `[ ]` placed directly after something: one of those somethings must have type `int`. There are therefore 3 candidates

1. `score`
2. `u`
3. `score`

So, we conclude that either `score` or `u` is an integer.

Looking at the context you provided

```
for u in score:
```

This line would have failed if `score` were not some iterable. `int`s are not iterable, therefore we conclude that `score` is not an integer. Which leads us to conclude that `u` (which is some element of the container `score`) is an integer.

Other comments about your code (which contains many problems):

1. It's suspicious that on one line you refer to `score1` (to which you do not refer anywhere else) while you use `score` on the next. Are you sure that the former shouldn't just be `score`?
2. `score.sort` accesses the `sort` method of `score` but does not call it. This makes sense in Python if you want to store that method somewhere, or pass it somewhere, but you are not doing that. So you have almost certainly forgotten to call the function: you do this by adding `()` after it, like so: `store.sort()`.
3. In your second code block `scoreJ1` and friends appear not to be defined anywhere, so this code cannot work, unless there is something else that you are not showing.

That should give you plenty to think about.

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed help, to answer your questions:
1. `score1` is meant to be another variable yes.
2. I was wondering why `score.sort` wasn't working properly haha, thanks!
3. This is because i've not put the whole code in the post, this is just a few bits of the code, but thanks for the concern

Comment: @ThomasAyling If you feel that the answer adequately addresses your question, then you might like to accept and/or upvote it (using the arrows and the tick in the left margin).